# Autopsy/SleuthKit in the courthouse?

Tags: forensics, hardware

I am studying digital forensics and have been working with both AccessData's FTK and Autopsy to analyze disks for different assignments.  I keep hearing that Autopsy findings should not be admitted in a court of law due to a lack of proof of reliablity, integrity, etc.

This is bothersome, as I find Autopsy to be the better option of the two digital forensics tools that I have used.  I know their are other options out there like EnCase, but I really find Autopsy to be a nice system to work with.  Has anyone here presented digital forensics findings that were derived from Autopsy or Sleuth Kit in a court of law, or found literature/precedence regarding this question.

I see that Autopsy received early funding from the U.S. Army and currently receives funding from the DHS, so I have to think it is at least somewhat regarded as a professional grade tool.

Comment: I'm flagging this question as off-topic as this is a legal question, not IT security question.

Comment: Is there no overlap between law and information security?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reliability & expertise in court is the responsibility of the examiner, not the tool. Voir dire will audit your training, experience, past testimony, etc. You can't audit or voir dire a tool, only a person (examiner). Use whatever tool you like, validate it with other tools as needed, update your tools regularly and don't be afraid to make a change if one tool isn't working for you. I used EnCase for years. I switched to Xways for a number of reasons. I also will use Autopsy to validate & for supplemental reasons. I may almost use Autopsy exclusively, but it doesn't create the forensic image, so that's a challenge.
Anyway, that's my 2 cents. Good luck!